# How to count width of same type elements till some element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

HTML:

```
<li class="home"><a href="/"><img alt="home" src="img/gohome.png"/></a></li>
<li class="portfolio closed" ><a href="portfolio"><span>portfolio</span></a></li>
<li class="articles opened" style="margin-right: 849px;"><a href="articles"><span>articles</span></a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="contact"><span>contact</span></a></li>
```

JS:

```
    $('nav li').each(function(index) { //Navigation total width
         navWidth += $(this).width();
    });
```

I have script like that which works, but I also have to count width of Li elements till some specific element basing on class for ex. portfolio. And i don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: "Width" as in the length of the content (including tags? within the <li>...</li> span?

Answer (score 2):

Another option with [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$("nav li:first").nextUntil(".portfolio").andSelf().each(function(index) {
     navWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

Comment: +1 I wanted to use `.nextUntil` somehow but could not come up with *how* ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I also always forget about `andSelf()` here :)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to exit the loop when you encounter an element with that class:

```
$('nav li').each(function() {
     if ($(this).hasClass('portfolio')) {
         return false;
     }
     navWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

Another way is to just select all the elements until the element with class `portfolio`. This can be done by getting the index of said element and select all elements up to that index:

```
var $lis = $('nav li');

$lis.slice(0, $lis.filter('.portfolio').index()).each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

This is under the assumption that all those `li` elements are siblings of each other.

**Reference:** [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)